# how to disable or hide minimize/maximize buttons in other application from c#?

Tags: c#

I open an Excel (2003) application from c#. I want that user will not be able to change it's size (it's opened maximized), therefore that the system menu and minimize/maximize buttons would be disabled or even hidden.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: That would be quite intrusive. Do your users really want that?

Comment: I build some kind of report in excel, the user has just to save it or quit and only then continue working. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's the code:

```
internal static class Utilities
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    internal extern static int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hwnd, int index, int value);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    internal extern static int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hwnd, int index);

    internal static void HideMinimizeAndMaximizeButtons(IntPtr hwnd)
    {
        const int GWL_STYLE = -16;
        const long WS_MINIMIZEBOX = 0x00020000L;
        const long WS_MAXIMIZEBOX = 0x00010000L;

        long value = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE);

        SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, (int)(value & ~WS_MINIMIZEBOX & ~WS_MAXIMIZEBOX));
    }
}
```

As stated in [Daniel Mošmondor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4296258/how-to-disable-or-hide-minimize-maximize-buttons-in-other-application-from-c/4296328#4296328) you need to find the Excel Windows handle, then just call the above code in this way:

```
Utilities.HideMinimizeAndMaximizeButtons(windowHandle);
```

N.B.
Maybe, depending on how you start the Excel process, you could already have the process or the window handle, so just use it without calling `Process.GetProcessesByName(...) / Process.GetProcesses()`

**EDIT:**

If you start your Excel application with:

```
ApplicationClass _excel = new ApplicationClass();
```

Just use the following code:

```
IntPtr windowHandle = new IntPtr(_excel.Hwnd);
Utilities.HideMinimizeAndMaximizeButtons(windowHandle);
```

Answer (score 1):

- find the process with the Excel in it
- wind the main window for it
- look up what flags should be set for the window (look SetWindowStyle and SetWindowStyleEx, maybe SetClass long)
- use PostMessage from your process to set the appropriate flag values

For testing, first create the app that will be used as a Excel mock just to see that you are doing it right from the 'other' app point of view.  After everything works, switch to real Excel.

Comment: THanks! Can you please mentions which functions will find proper process and it's mainn window? (i'm pretty new to c#...)

Comment: No, you can't change window styles with PostMessage.

Comment: Leon, you should post the code you're using to start the excel application. For example if you start it through `Process.Start` then you already have the process and you only need to find the window... So, in order to have a complete answer, please post your code ;)

Comment: my code is - using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel; ApplicationClass _excel = newApplicationClass();